# Apache 2: issue redirecting root url from http to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache-config

I have an issue redirecting from the http site to the https site.

This **index.php** file is in the root folder, redirecting to a suburl:

```
<?php
header("Location: /news/");
?>
```

the url `https://www.example.com` is correctly redirecting to `https://www.example.com/news/`

the url `https://www.example.com/index.php` is correctly redirecting to `https://www.example.com/news/`

the url `http://www.example.com/index.php` is correctly redirecting to `https://www.example.com/news/`

however the url `http://www.example.com` is showing an empty directory, as in the image below:

[image]

these are the config files:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs
        ServerAlias example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs
        ServerAlias example.com

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

How can I correctly redirect from `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/news/` ?

Comment: Can the person who downgraded the question please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has two options -- Virtual Host Redirection, and Request Rewriting. Adapt the following configuration fragments to your needs.

**Virtual Host Redirection**

To be prefered as being simpler and safer. *Redirect* an HTTP virtual host (Port 80) to a HTTPS virtual host (Port 443) via the virtual hosts configuration:

```
# Listening for HTTP connections
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    # permanently redirects to the site's HTTPS version
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

# Listening for HTTPS connections
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    SSLEngine On

    # Further configurations...
</VirtualHost>
```

**Request Rewriting**

Alternatively -- usually, when the virtual hosts config is not accessible -- one can edit the `.htaccess` file (create it, if necessary) to *rewrite* HTTP to HTTPS requests. For that the module [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) has to be enabled, so

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

in `httpd.conf` has to be set (and usually is, by default). Then add to the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Enable rewriting
RewriteEngine On 
# Check for HTTPS, if no, execute next line
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Redirect to HTTPS with status code 301 (moved permanently)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you, I used the "Virtual Host Redirection" successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</virtualHost>
```

Type the code into the conf file.

Comment: Request rewriting should usually work, however -- as far as I am aware of -- virtual host redirection should be prefered when possible, as it doesn't depend on a module (mod_rewrite) and is therefore more straightforward.